# Angularjs directive callback or listener

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have previously created a directive to allow me to get user id/names from a internal function. I needed this because I needed to do this same procedure for multiple user roles. It all works as I want, but now I ran into a situation where in one case (that I know of) where once the values from the directive are set into the model, I need to set some additional scope flags for handling some processes. I'm not sure how to go about this...is it a callback somehow that is only called when something is passed into the directive or do I use some listener to see if a value changes and then set the flags I need? Like I said, I do not always need to do this so whatever I do has to be flexible enough not to always be required/occur. I seem to think it needs to be something in the directive, but I just don't know enough to know how to go about it.

Here is my current directive that does exactly what I want in setting two model values (the name and id of a user).

```
app.directive('nameUser', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {               
     idModel : '=',
     nameModel : '='
  },
  templateUrl : 'app/views/nameUser.html',          
  link : function($scope,nameModel,idModel){       

       $scope.searchName = function(searchQuery, bar){
         var bar = "#loadingBar" + bar;
         if(searchQuery && searchQuery.length >= 3){
            $(bar).slideDown();
              $http.get("/read/userinfo/" + searchQuery).success(function(data){
                  $scope.nameSearchResults = data;
                  $(bar).slideUp();
               });
         }
   }

    $scope.selectName = function(pl){
       $scope.nameModel = pl.name;    
       $scope.idModel = pl.user_id;  
       $scope.nameSearchResults = {};
    }
  }
};
```

My HTML to call the directive is (this is called within a ng-repeat of a table:

```
<name-user id-model="request.requesterID" name-model="request.requester"></name-user>
```

Can someone help me to know what to do so, for instance, I can set a value in my controller to true if an id/name has been set?  So far, I only need this in one particular place so not every time the directive is called.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle where the problem is reproduced?

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question in asking it? "...where once the values from the directive are set into the model, I need to set some additional scope flags for handling some processes" -- why not just do what ever it is you need to do immediately after the results come back from the server (in the success callback, just after `$scope.nameSearchResults = data;` ?

Comment: thanks. I ended up figuring another way around it....when I need to see if there is a value, I added a function to call from the view to see if the value was set and then do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a function in the view when displaying the value that is called and it does what I needed done. thanks for the help.